# Pulling wire under Stairs

Tags: electrical, wiring

Have two questions and have attached a picture for each. Thank you in advance.

1. Is this ok to pull wire under stairs ?. I can't pull through ceiling joists because 2 joists completely blocking my way due to duck work.
2. In the 2nd picture, I have a pole between two studs in one of the side of the stair's . I am running wire behind the pole ( between studs), and the wire will in direct contact with dry wall.

Is it ok to wire like this and will this pass inspection ?

I don't think its specific to local city.

Please assist and thank you in advance.

Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Also [see discussion here](https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/pulling-electric-wire-under-stairs.712689/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this area is going to be enclosed it will be fine.

The only thing I might see as a problem is the telecom panel.
on the final some inspectors won’t allow the cable to be open below 8’.
Since they will call it an electrical closet (no clothing racks or flammable storage).

Easy fix on the stair 1/2” plywood or 1/2” Sheetrock covering that cavity would be code compliant.

The pipe being on the back side of the stair I don’t see a way to cover the wiring. if it is behind a wall it will be fine, you have the wire centered on the stud left of the pipe but on edge of the right one  that’s not a problem if that area will be enclosed. I can’t tell from the photo.
After re reading direct contact or pinched will get a flag, again easy fix 2x4 nailed flat under the stair will make less storage under the stair but keep the inspector from making you do it later (you can bump out that 1 stud bay 1-1/2” and that will also work.

Comment: Depending on where I am getting it inspected it would either be fine or need sheetrock.   You can always add sheetrock later.    If kids are accessing this room then just add it now - its like a 30 min job and each sheet only needs 4-5 screws and no need to mud.

Comment: Thanks Ed for your answer. What you have mentioned make sense to me.

Comment: Our thanks come from up votes and accepted answers the check marks , when an answer is accepted it helps others with similar question find a answer that worked for them.

Comment: Have already voted. thanks